# PyQtGraph - Open 'file save dialog' using button instead of through context menu

Tags: python, plot, save, pyqt, pyqtgraph

In pyqtgraph there is option to save plot as image/csv/svg/etc. just by clicking right mouse button on the plot and choosing 'Export.." option. There is also possibility to export plot like this: (assuming pw is my plot)

```
ex1 = pg.exporters.CSVExporter(pw.plotItem)
ex1.export('test.csv')
ex2 = pg.exporters.SVGExporter(pw.plotItem)
ex2.export('test.svg')
ex3 = pg.exporters.ImageExporter(pw.plotItem)
ex3.export('test.img')
```

The problem is that I don't want to use right-click menu (and so on) neither to directly save plot in fixed format and to predefined path. I want a function that when called will open up this same 'save file dialog' that hides under 'Export..' menu option. I will then connect it to a button or whatever and voilà :)

Any ideas?

Comment: You may use the dialog QtGui.QFileDIalog.getSaveFileName, connect it to a push button so the user can select a name and the save location for your file. When you have the name, use the export method provided by pyqtgraph.

Comment: I did but it is more like a workaround option.. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to do this and and this is how I did it.

```
from pyqtgraph.GraphicsScene import exportDialog
exportDialog = exportDialog.ExportDialog(pw.plotItem.scene())
exportDialog.show(pw.plotItem)
```

This creates an Export dialog that targets the GraphicsScene holding the plotItem.